# Show only first occurence pine script v5

Tags: pine-script

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztSww.png)

```
//@version=5
indicator("Mean reverse strategi", timeframe="1D")
bool first = false

a=0
b=0
c=0
d=0
e=0
f=0
buy=0
sell=0

williammax = ta.highest(10)
williammin = ta.lowest(10)
_pr = 100 * (close - williammax) / (williammax - williammin)


if math.max(open, close, high, low)<ta.sma(close, 10)
    a:=1
if _pr<-85
    b:=1
if ta.rsi(close, 2)<10
    c:=1
if a==1 and b==1 and c==1
    buy:=-1

if _pr > -15
    e:=1
if buy[1]==-1 or buy[2]==-1 or buy[3]==-1 or buy[4]==-1 or buy[5]==-1 or buy[6]==-1 or buy[7]==-1 or buy[8]==-1 or buy[9]==-1 or buy[10]==-1 or buy[11]==-1 or buy[12]==-1
    f:=1
if f!=1 and e==1
    sell:=1

plot(buy, color=#50EF53)
plot(sell, color=#F93822FF)
```

I want only the first occurrence of the red to be shown. After that the red should be zero until the indicator has shown green. basically only first occurence of red should be shown and after when the indicator has shown green again it should reset to allow the first occurence of red again.

Answer (score 0):

You can add aa variable ex. greenoccured which will be reset to 0 when green will occur. It will be incremented when red occurs. You can display red only when greenoccured is <=1. Example below

```
//@version=5
indicator("Mean reverse strategi", timeframe="1D")
bool first = false

a=0
b=0
c=0
d=0
e=0
f=0
buy=0
sell=0

var greenoccured=0

williammax = ta.highest(10)
williammin = ta.lowest(10)
_pr = 100 * (close - williammax) / (williammax - williammin)


if math.max(open, close, high, low)<ta.sma(close, 10)
    a:=1
if _pr<-85
    b:=1
if ta.rsi(close, 2)<10
    c:=1
if a==1 and b==1 and c==1
    buy:=-1
    greenoccured:=0
if _pr > -15
    e:=1
if buy[1]==-1 or buy[2]==-1 or buy[3]==-1 or buy[4]==-1 or buy[5]==-1 or buy[6]==-1 or buy[7]==-1 or buy[8]==-1 or buy[9]==-1 or buy[10]==-1 or buy[11]==-1 or buy[12]==-1
    f:=1
if f!=1 and e==1
    sell:=1
    greenoccured:=greenoccured+1

plot(buy, color=#50EF53)
plot(greenoccured<=1?sell:0, color=#F93822FF)
```